# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found when trying to import pyzbar

Tags: python, qr-code

I'm trying to import pyzbar to use pyzbar.decode in my code. This is my code:

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
```

And this is the error i got and i can't get rid of it. Tried reinstalling Visual C++ Redistributable Packages 2013 as it seems that this helped some people, but it was in vain for me.

Can someone help me? I never used pyzbar before. Thanks

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 58, in load
    dependencies, libzbar = load_objects(Path(''))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 52, in load_objects
    for dep in dependencies
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    for dep in dependencies
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyzbar import pyzbar
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\pyzbar.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .wrapper import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 143, in <module>
    c_uint_p,    # minor
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 136, in zbar_function
    return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 115, in load_libzbar
    libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 60, in load
    dependencies, libzbar = load_objects(Path(__file__).parent)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 52, in load_objects
    for dep in dependencies
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    for dep in dependencies
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application```
````

Comment: Did you try installing pyzbar ?
You can do it by `pip3 install pyzbar`

Comment: @ShubhamJain i used ```conda install pyzbar```

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll work, you can try reinstalling
`conda install pyzbar --force-reinstall`

Comment: @ShubhamJain same error